# Is it possible to use environment variables inside docker daemon configuration file

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-daemon, docker-registry-mirror

### background:

We are using `registry_mirrors` & `insecure_registries` options in `docker` `daemon.json` file. We would like to **stop** setting the location of the `mirrors` **hard-coded**.

### Question

Is it possible to use `env variable` inside `daemon.json`? So instead of writing `ip` `X.Y.Z.W:PORT` one would write  `${REPO1}`. Hopefully it will be possible to change `REPO1` var without restarting the `daemon`

### Remarks

The solution must allow to change the `repo` location **without** restarting the daemon

### EDIT

it is not possible to use the following inside daemon.json
1. ${VAR_NAME}

#### Possible workaround

Use custom hostname and redefine it in `/etc/hosts`. This allows to change repo `ip` without restarting the daemon. **But** it does not allow to change the `port` or the `protocol`

#### Possible workaround 2

> Some options can be reconfigured when the daemon is running without requiring to restart the process. We use the SIGHUP signal in Linux to reload, and a global event in Windows with the key Global\docker-daemon-config-$PID. The options can be modified in the configuration file but still will check for conflicts with the provided flags. The daemon fails to reconfigure itself if there are conflicts, but it won’t stop execution[source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file)

So one can edit the `registry` and do `sudo systemctl reload docker` or `sudo kill -SIGHUP $(pidof dockerd)`. This does **not** restart the existing containers nor the daemon itself